# Why is Mongodb not working with foreign language?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using node.js and express with mongodb.

I just saved some data in a foreign language(different character set than English). And I tried to pull the data from the database and it didn't show anything. It's ignoring it.

What's wrong here? and How do you fix it?

Comment: We need a bit more information to be able to help. Can you [edit] your question to show 1: the code which inserted the data; 2: the state of the data after it has been saved; 3: the code you are using to read back the data ?

Comment: I can't recall having any troubles saving foreign texts to MongoDB, so we definitely need more information.